# Civi Ajax API Search by Multiple Tags

Tags: api, javascript, tags

As sort of a followup to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/civicrm-ajax-api-searching-by-tag).  I am trying to retrieve all the contacts who have `tag:5` AND who have `tag:7`.  I tried the following code:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "tag": [5,7]
  "return": ["tag","first_name"]
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

However, this returns all the contacts who have `tag:5` OR `tag:7`.  Is there any way to do this through the API?  The only other solution I can think of is sifting through the objects using some client-side javascript.